# Authenticating domain users from .NET application when domain controller is not available

Tags: .net, active-directory

I have a scenario where after initial setup of the machine the domain controller will not be available for authentication. i.e Initially when the application runs it can connect to the active directory. Subsequently connection to the domain controller is not available. Is there any way of authenticating the users against the active directory in offline mode.

One possible approach when custom authentication(where in uname,pwd is stored in db) is used is cache all the user details in the client machine and then when the network is not available authenticate it in the client against the cached user details.

I also know that the windows caches the ad users details in the local machine if the user has logged in from the machine using the credentials atleast once. Is it possible to use this from a .NET application ?

Any other solution for the scenario is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware that could solve your problem is to create a [Read-Only Domain Controller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732801%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (on the IIS machine would work, but definitely not recommended).

Comment: In this instance, I do not know where your server is, nor who has access.  There is no compatibility problem between the two I am aware of (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732790), just security issues.